# невозможный абстрактный класс - запечатал абстрактное свойство

Tags: c#, наследование

хотел запретить присвоение значений свойству, оставив возможность определить геттер в следующем наследнике. но свойство удачно запечатывается, IDE не видит ошибки.

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public abstract int this[int index]{ get; protected set; }
}

public abstract class Inheritor : Base
{
    public sealed override int this[int index]
    {
        protected set => throw new System.InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

подскажите, как запечатать один из методов свойства, не повлияв на другой [метод]

Comment: на C# нельзя запечатать один акцессор. просто синтаксис такое не поддерживает. на уровне IL - можно.

Comment: @PashaPash спасибо, а так хотелось использовать синтаксический сахар... надеюсь, красивое решение найдется. у меня в оригинальной проблеме индексатор вместо свойства, и брать значения не от куда

Comment: @PashaPash беда в том что синтаксис IDE поддерживает, а унаследоваться нельзя. оно даже откомпилировалось (вроде)

Answer (score 1):

решил сделать как не хотел: добавил абстрактный метод

---

вот как изменился второй класс:

```
public sealed override int this[int index]
{
    get => Get_This(index);
    protected set => throw new System.InvalidOperationException();
}

protected abstract int Get_This(int index);
```